# melt some values of a column to a separate column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:
[image]

But I want to have new data frame with the sate is a seperate column as below:

[image]

DO you know how to do it using Python? Thank you so much.

Comment: If you will read this excel sheet in python the scenario will be different. Try to use this https://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-report.html

Comment: What is `print (df.index[:10])` of DataFrame?

Comment: @Stackpy when I read this excel file in Python, there is no difference between the state and county since this excel file is not a pivot table

Comment: Could you provide the DataFrame you are working with and the code you've tried so far? The question you ask is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's say we have this data:

```
data = {
    'County':[
        '    USA',
        '',
        '    Alabama',
        'Autauga',
        'Baldwin',
        'Barbour',
        '',
        '    Alaska',
        'Aleutians',
        'Anchorage',
        '',
        '    Arizona',
        'Apache',
        'Cochise'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

We could use empty lines as marks of a new state like this:

```
spaces = (df.County == '')
states = spaces.shift().fillna(False)
df['States'] = df.loc[states, 'County']
df['States'].ffill(inplace=True)
```

In the code above `states` is a mask of cells under empty lines, where states are located. At the next step we connect states by genuine index to the new column. After that we apply forward fill of `NaN` values which will duplicate each states until the next one.

Additionally we could do some cleaning. This, IMO, would be more relevant somewhat earlier, but anyway:

```
df['States'] = df['States'].fillna('')
df.loc[spaces, 'States'] = ''
df.loc[states, 'States'] = ''
```

This method rely on the structure with spaces between states. Let's make something different in case if there's no spaces between states. Say we have some data like this (no empty rows, no spaces around names):

```
data = [
    'USA',
    'Alabama',
    'Autauga',
    'Baldwin',
    'Barbour',
    'Alaska',
    'Aleutians',
    'Anchorage',
    'Arizona',
    'Apache',
    'Cochise'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['County'])
```

We can work with a list of known states and `pandas.Series.isin` in this case. All the other logic can stay the same:

```
States = ['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona',...]
mask = df.County.isin(States)
df = df.assign(**{'States':df.loc[mask, 'County']}).ffill()
```

Comment: it does not work. I run your code and it simply generate the same another column of County. not the column with only state name

Comment: @Ng.Alina What data did you use? And what is your environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an example dataset it would be helpful and we can work on it. I created an example dataset like the table below:

[image: data]

numbers were given randomly.

I am not sure if there is an easy way. You should put all your states in a list beforehand. The main idea behind my approach is detecting the empty rows between the states. The first string coming after the empty row is the state name and filling this name until the empty row is reached. (since there might be another country name like the United States and probably comes from an empty row, we created the states list beforehand to avoid mistakes.)
Here is my approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

states = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona"]
data['states'] = np.nan #creating states column

flag = ""
for index, value in data['location'].iteritems():
    if pd.notnull(value):
        if value in states:
            flag = value
        data['states'].iloc[index] = flag

#relocating 'states' column to the second position in the dataframe
column = data.pop('states')
data.insert(1,'states',column)
```

And the result:
[image: result]

Comment: it still does not work. I don;t know how to attach the csv file here. when I run you code, it doesnot create a right column with name of states

Comment: can you provide what you have done so far? I mean, how do you read your file?  Also, please run df.head(10) and share the result with us.